# Arduino LCD not working

Tags: arduino, potentiometer, character-lcd

I'm getting started with LCD projects for Arduino, but for some reason, the LCD won't display characters.

I'm using [this tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LiquidCrystal) from the Arduino website, and [this LCD](https://www.adafruit.com/products/181) with an Uno R3 board. This is the circuit diagram of my setup:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1uGW3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I don't have any formal eduction in EE (yet), but I think that the issue may be that where the tutorial's diagram shows the LCD's first two pins as being `Vss` and `Vcc`, the actual pins on the LCD are marked `Gnd` and `VDD`, respectively.

The code I'm using is essentially the same as that provided on the tutorial page:

```
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows: 
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {
  // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
  // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  // print the number of seconds since reset:
  lcd.print(millis()/1000);
}
```

It should display "hello, world!" on the LCD. However, when I power up the circuit, the display's backlight turns on, but no text appears. Around 3 seconds after powering up, all of the LCD's characters flash full white (the screen displays white-on-blue) for a fraction of a second, before returning to a blank, backlit screen indefinitely. Turning the potentiometer does nothing, although having it set to less than 10k ohms for any more than 5 seconds causes the chip underneath the display to overheat (I already burned out one display this way by setting the pot to about 5k ohms without noticing the damage being done).

Is this a common issue? Is there a solution, or an explanation for why this happens (a dud display)?

Comment: For me it's a common issue whenever I hook up an LCD,  either I'll get no text, or a garbled mix of text and symbols. I always wire it wrong. I just disconnect everything and start over wiring it again, making sure to wire it correctly. Another issue I've had with LCDs is a insufficient contrast setting (in software).

Comment: @Grimtech I've wired the LCD up about three or four times before this, and double-checked every time after the first one burned out. It's unlikely that it's a wiring issue; and it's not showing garbled characters, just a completely white character space.

Comment: Looking at the circuit I wouldn't expect the backlight to come on because BL1 & BL2 aren't connected. The datasheet shows using a 20-50K pot which might be worth trying, maybe use an 18K resistor between the pot and ground for a start and that will at least stop your current problem when turned down too low.

Comment: @PeterJ I would think so, too, but since it does, one might assume that those are just used to actually regulate the backlight brightness; the backlight itself might be powered by the `VDD`. The main pot is used for contrast control; a second one could be used for backlight control.

Comment: @JulesMazur, not 100% sure but if that's the case the part you have probably doesn't match their datasheet. That LED backlight would need about a 1R 1W current limit resistor due to the 100mA draw / 4.1V voltage drop of the LED. That's a lot more power than a small pot will be able to handle.

Comment: @PeterJ could you post the datasheet you're referencing?

Comment: @JulesMazur, it was the one linked on the product page above: https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/TC1602A-01T.pdf

Comment: @PeterJ Thanks. I added two 10K ohm resistors before the 5V line gets to the pot (so, there's a total of 30K ohm resistance before the LCD), and there's a visibly higher contrast on the display; however, it still displays nonsense characters, and the back of the display heats up to about 70º C, which is about the same temperature it reached before adding in the extra resistors. I'll try adding two more resistors in an attempt to solve the overheating issue. EDIT: Now up to 60K ohms resistance and the temperature is down to 55º C.

Comment: Your diagram shows R/W being tied to Vdd. Are you sure you wired it up that way? If anything, it should go to GND.

Comment: My mistake, I must've screwed up the diagram when I was cleaning up some of the wiring.

Comment: You can double check your wiring with this image: http://www.adafruit.com/index.php?main_page=popup_image_additional&pID=181&pic=0&products_image_large_additional=images/large/LCDblue162ard_LRG.jpg

Comment: @jippie Thanks, I think I hooked up the pot wrong.

Comment: The lcd should not get hot no matter where the pot is set to. Generally, the voltage on VO will need to be low - around 0.2 volts to get a display out. You should be able to see characters without the backlight. Do you have a voltmeter to check voltages at the display connector?

Comment: I undid the entire circuit and reconnected everything (not for the first time). For some reason, the overheating issue is now completely gone; the voltage between the `Gnd` and `VDD` terminals is 5V. The only problem now is that it won't display text, but rather the entire top row is solid white blocks, while the bottom row is off, but I think this is a software issue rather than hardware. Thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: Update: the problem's solved, the LCD no longer overheats, the pot works, and text is displayed correctly.

Comment: What did the problem turn out to be?

Comment: @JRobert I can't say for sure. The problem on the software end (which caused the screen to display blank) was a typo while declaring one of the pins, and I solved the hardware (overheating) issue by re-wiring the setup entirely.

Comment: I've tripped over LCD protocols more than once. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

You have probably turned the LCD Display up-side down (since you have the back lights on, it is the same pins as Vcc and Vss when its up-side down).

Other important things to check:

- Add +5v and ground to the last two pins (the backlight) otherwise it's hard to see whats showing.
- Check that the potentiometer is correctly connected.